# Duplication in csv reading

Tags: c#, csv, converters

[image]

I'm running into some problems in my code where when it reads the SQL file it duplicates entries and some times puts them in the wrong order. I've been stepping through my code and checking values but I haven't been able to find anything, there should only be 4 entries.

```
    private void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Opens a browse box to allow the user to select which file, only CSV's allow allowed
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        //empties text box when clicked | loads file location and name to load directory text box at top
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ConvertedText.Text = string.Empty;
            LoadDirectory.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
        }
        string filename = LoadDirectory.Text;
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        string[] Fields;
        string outfile = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            outfile += "IF EXISITS (SELECT USERID FROM WUSERS WHERE USERID='" + Fields[0] + "')" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "begin" + Environment.NewLine;
            ConvertedText.AppendText(outfile);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never clear `outfile` between passes in the for loop.

Either declare

```
string outfile = "";
```

inside the loop or have

```
outfile = "";
```

at the very end of the loop

Comment: You sir are an absolute life saver thank you so much <3